# High school nuclear physics experiments and activities

Tags: radiation, education, home-experiment

I'm looking for some interesting activities regarding nuclear physics in high school.

I already have:
- building a cloud chamber with dry ice or peltier modules
- simulating radioactive decay with dice
- simulating Rutherford's experiment hitting with glass marbles a hidden target and trying to figure out the shape

Any fun/didactic/interesting/innovative idea?

Thanks!

Comment: At my community college we have a lab we do with 137Cs elution sources and Geiger counters: http://www.lightandmatter.com/lab_206.pdf . Microcurie sources are relatively cheap, you can ship them through US mail, and they can be disposed of by throwing them in the trash.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer, but if I can think of any more I will edit this:

The standard from TV shows, a chain reaction with ping pong balls and mousetraps https://youtu.be/0v8i4v1mieU

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dated, but when I was a teenager, the hands down best source was the Amateur Scientist column in Scientific American by C. L. Stong. It is not available in book form at https://archive.org/details/TheAmateurScientist

See the chapter titled A Homemade Atom Smasher (As I said, a bit dated...) For less than the average cost of a set of golf clubs you can equip yourself for playing with electrons - and learn much first hand about the structure of matter.

Or The Millikan Oil-Drop experiment. Suspend a drop of oil in mid-air by means of electrostatic attraction - and you can accurately measure the charge on a single electron.